# Finding Point on surface, $n$ line $\parallel$ to another line

Tags: calculus

Working on some questions for my final review, 
Looking for the point on the surface $z=xy$ where the $n$ line is $\parallel$ to the line $x(t)=1+t, y(t)=2+3t, z(t)=3-2t$

-What I did was find the gradient of $z = (y,x,-1)$ and the direction of the line is $<1,3,-2>$
not sure where to go from here. Would anyone happen to know, Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to MSE! It really helps readability to format questions using MathJax (see FAQ). I updated your question as an example, please study it and make sure I got it right. Regards

Comment: What is the $n$ line?  Is it the normal to the surface?

Comment: n line is (normal line)

Answer (score 1):

In order for your two vectors to be parallel, there must be some nonzero $\lambda$ such that $\lambda(x,y,-1)=(1,3,-2)$.  Clearly then $\lambda=2$.  Solving some equations, it follows that
$$(x,y,z)=(\frac{1}{2},\frac{3}{2},\frac{3}{4})$$
is the desired point on $z=xy$.